# PHPMyAdmin Import large (70 MB) file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a 70 MB .sql file in PHPMYADMIN but it give me the limit error:

> You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.

I have changed the values of `upload_max_filesize, memory_limit and post_max_size` in the php.ini and have restarted xampp but its still not working ??? please help

Comment: Which limit error do you get? Please show the error message.

Comment: `You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.`

Comment: `mysql dbname < importfile.sql`

Comment: Try to use Execute Large Script tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Comment: Maybe split it into different parts. That's what I do for my imports

Comment: http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/ , http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#faq

Comment: @thetaiko `pv importfile.sql | mysql dbname` gives you a progress bar.  `pv` is available in EPEL for RHEL/CentOS, and probably via Your Favorite Package Manager™ in other distributions.

Comment: @BMDan - I think `pv` might become my new favorite thing.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the phpmyadmin import formulary is block your upload.
Look next to upload form field the max value, if it is less then 70mb you can  increase it on MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field.

Comment: Yes this field still shows 16 M ...

Comment: Can you please specify the hidden field you are talking about ???

Comment: the field is on html formulary bellow the upload file field, it is responsable to limit the max size value to upload.

Comment: if it not work, maybe this tip  can help you: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#faq1_16